# Heuristic & Approximation algorithms

Tags: algorithms

I just came to know the definition of r-approximation algorithm. I just want to know whether infinite-approximation algorithm is a heuristic algorithm?

Is heuristic algorithm is an infinite-approximation algorithm?

Comment: @Yves Daoust But both the algorithms are obtaining the solutions which are valid and acceptable. So, how can you say that both the concepts are unrelated?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can you please elaborate what you have said in the previous comment